# Best statistical test for a 3 x 3 confusion matrix

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confusion-matrix

I have a 3 by 3 confusion matrix:

```
+---------+------+--------+-----+
|         | Good | Medium | Bad |
+---------+------+--------+-----+
| Class 1 | 314  | 176    | 95  |
+---------+------+--------+-----+
| Class 2 | 184  | 275    | 126 |
+---------+------+--------+-----+
| Class 3 | 87   | 134    | 364 |
+---------+------+--------+-----+
```

I would now like to state something about that elements of class 1 are more likely to be identified as 'good' compared to elements of class 3. Similarly, I want to compare class 2 with class 3 and class 1 with class 2 as well. What would be a correct statistical approach/test to do this?